# hash table, destructor error

Tags: c++, hashtable, destructor

I am trying to test my hashtable piece by piece and right now I am just trying to create the object. However, I am receiving an error in my destructor. It says: `expected primary-expression before ';' token`.

This is what I have the destructor:

```
HashTable::~HashTable
{
     delete [ ] HashTable;
}
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What array are you trying to delete? (And how can it have the same name as your class?)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to delete the type HashTable which is futile. Probably you meant to delete some class member.

Comment: And if you are trying to delete a class member, it might reflect a questionable decision in your class design. Also, unless you are building `HashTable` strictly for educational purposes, you should instead consider using [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).

Comment: @DavidRR `std::unordered_map` is the hash table. Plain `std::map` is managed by order, not hashes, and has associated differences in which situations it's best at.

Answer (score 0):

You try to delete type in this code?! 
if you want delete an array in destructor try:

```
HashTable::~HashTable
{
     delete[] ArrayName;
}
```